# Getting authorized access error from Spotify with spotify-wrapper

Tags: javascript, api, express, spotify

I'm trying to use the Spotify wrapper to use my app, I manage to hit Spotify's Account Service and the page to authorize the app to use a users spotify account information but I get an internal 500 server error:

`index.js:6 POST https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize/accept 500 (Internal Server Error)`

```
// Set up Spotify API wrapper
const scopes = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email'];
const STATE_KEY = 'spotify_auth_state';

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  const state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(STATE_KEY, state);
  res.redirect(spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state));
});

app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  const { code, state } = req.query;
  const storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[STATE_KEY] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#/error/state mismatch');
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(STATE_KEY);

    spotifyApi
      .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
      .then(data => {
        const { expires_in, access_token, refresh_token } = data.body;

        // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
        spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

        spotifyApi.getMe().then(({ body }) => {
          console.log(body);
        });

        res.redirect('/search');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.redirect('/#/error/invalid token');
      });
  }
});
```

This is my endpoint on that page:

`https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8888%2Fcallback%2F&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=k4ogwe4h53i00000`

Not entirely sure what's happening. I thought it was initially a state mismatch but the state generated is fine. Having trouble pinpointing where the error is. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Like the error says it's an internal server error. Something is wrong on their end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your redirect URI in the [developer dashboard](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/dashboard), ensuring that it's **exactly** the same as the one you're using in your app.

We're aware of the poor error handling for the invalid redirect URI error and it's being fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked that. It's the same. Kinda stumped! Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you let me know the client ID I can check out what redirect URI is registered on the back end :)

Comment: That would be great, hmm... should I private message it to you? Or just post it here?

Comment: I ended up changing it and now i'm getting a completely different error for some reason:

![image](https://i.imgur.com/audiyD5.png)

Network tab in the dev tools is saying there was a bad request for `https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize/accept`

Comment: Fun fact: that's actually the same error, which is invalid redirect URI. There's an ongoing issue with the error handling for that error and we're working on fixing it. You can either post here or private message (just don't include the client secret)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Client ID is: 71dbf25807e34dfaa54a945e7676250a

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues with your authorization, if you go to `https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=71dbf25807e34dfaa54a945e7676250a&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8888%2Fcallback%2F&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=k4ogwe4h53i00000&show_dialog=true` and click accept it redirects as you would expect

Comment: [link that doesn't have weird formatting](https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=71dbf25807e34dfaa54a945e7676250a&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8888%2Fcallback%2F&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=k4ogwe4h53i00000&show_dialog=true)

Comment: Yup, that all works. The problem comes when I give authorization, now i'm getting an `error mismatch`, but I'm pretty sure the issue is on my end. Just having trouble figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163282/discussion-between-arirawr-and-carlosg90).